# Javascript API progress feedback to the front end

Tags: node.js, rest, frontend, backend

I have a REST API that does a batch process. Depending on how big and complex the batch is it can take a variable amount of time. Is there any way to send intermittent progress responses from node to the front end so it can be displayed as a progress bar?

Comment: Either use WebSockets to receive events from the server, like progress status or what ever, or the client could pull the status via xhr. For that the http status code 202 was created: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_success In my eyes this question is opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, But socket.io might help in this scenario since it creates a two-way communication channel.